# Users can't view photos posted to Facebook group using Python facebook-sdk

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-oauth

I've to upload about 20 albums of 20 or so photos of new inventory at a specific time to a closed FB group.

I wrote a small python 2.7 script that grabs my user access token, creates the albums, uploads the pictures and posts a message saying the photos are ready.

I went live with it last night after testing it and everything seemed to work great. That's when **we started getting messages from users that they couldn't access the albums. It appears to be a permissions problem, and I have no idea what I need to do to solve it**.  Here's the snippet of code in question:

```
group_id = 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'

products = {
    'Amelia'  : 'Amelia Dress ~ $65 plus $3 shipping',
    'Azure'   : 'Azure Skirt ~ $35 plus $3 shipping',
    'Cassie'  : 'Cassie ~Pencil Skirt~ $35 plus $3 shipping',
    'Classic' : 'Classic Tee ~ $35 plus $3 shipping',
    'Irma'    : 'Irma ~LuLaRoe Signature Tunic Tee~ $35 plus $3 shipping',
    'Jade'    : 'Jade ~Exercise Leggings~ $55 plus $3 shipping',
    'Julia'   : 'Julia Dress ~ $45 plus $3 shipping',
    'Madison' : 'Madison Skirt ~ $46 plus $3 shipping',
    'Monroe'  : 'Monroe Kimono ~ $48 plus $3 shipping',
    'Nicole'  : 'Nicole Dress ~ $48 plus $3 shipping',
    'Patrick' : 'Patrick Tee ~ $40 plus $3 shipping',
    'Perfect' : 'Perfect Tee ~ $36 plus $3 shipping',
    'Randy'   : 'Randy Baseball Tee ~ $35 plus $3 shipping'
}

# Oauth token
graph = facebook.GraphAPI('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

for product in products.keys():
    # Create album in group.
    print '*** Working on ' + product + ' ***'
    resp = graph.put_object(group_id, 'albums', name=products[product])

    postdir = 'C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Dropbox\\' + product + '\\post'

    for file in os.listdir(postdir):
        print "Posting " + file
        photo = open(os.path.join(postdir,file), 'rb')
        graph.put_photo(photo, album_id=str(resp['id']))
        photo.close()

    graph.put_object(parent_object=group_id, connection_name='feed',
                     message=product + ' album is loaded! :)')
```

Comment: _“messages from users that they couldn't access the albums”_ – and that means what exactly? // To rule out the obvious: Your app is set “live” (top of Status&Review tab), right?

Comment: Argh, no!  I'll give that a shot and see how it goes. This is all completely new to me. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks a million CBroe. That completely fixed the problem!